# Cannot access the key generated .pub file

Tags: 14.04, ssh

generated keygen files

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa):  \Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in \Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse.
Your public key has been saved in \Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse.pub.
```

but when i try to access the content of .pub files i am getting below error

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ cat \Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse.pub
cat: UsersSeven.sshlinuxCourse.pub: No such file or directory
```

tried this as well

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ cat Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse.pub
cat: UsersSeven.sshlinuxCourse.pub: No such file or directory

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:~$ cat /Users/Seven/.ssh/linuxCourse.pub
cat: UsersSeven.sshlinuxCourse.pub: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a valid path to `ssh-keygen`:

```
\Users\Seven\.ssh\linuxCourse
```

is not valid. You should use forward slashes `/` instead of `\`. And also `/Users/foo/bar` is really unusual (it seems like you are on OSX). Your home dir on linux is in `/home/[your username]` and the path proposed by `ssh-keygen` tells us that your username is `vagrant`. So store your key somewhere in `/home/vagrant`. Or just leave the default path `/home/vagrant/.ssh/linuxCourse` it is the best place to store your keys.

**Edit**:
So what happened is `ssh-keygen` created the files named **\Users\Seven.ssh\linuxCourse** and **\Users\Seven.ssh\linuxCourse.pub** in the folder where you executed the `ssh-keygen` command.

Comment: thanks i regenerated the key using path **/home/vagrant/.ssh/linuxCourse** . Now i can able to access the contents

Answer (score 0):

You generated the key somewhere else, because you used backslashes instead of normal slashes.

You can access the file like from your home directory:

```
cat "/Users/Seven/.ssh/linuxCourse.pub"
```

It is not in the `.ssh` directory, but in current directory with all these characters you wrote. You would find out if you would try `ls` in current directory.